# CodeIgniter / Gmail SMTP timeout on MAMP / IIS

Tags: codeigniter, iis, smtp, gmail, mamp

I'm trying to use the CI email class to send email, but the page just hangs when it tries to send. I have tried on both IIS and now on my Mac using MAMP. The code is the same as has been copied all over the place and seems to work for everybody else!

```
    $config = Array(
                'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => '465',
                'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
                'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
                'mailtype'  => 'html',
                'starttls'  => true
            );

        $this->load->library('email', config);
        $this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'George');
        $this->email->to('email@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('hey this is an email');
        $this->email->message('this is the content of the email');
        $this->email->send();
```

Any other server settings to try??

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm embarrassed to say that I was missing the $ in:

```
$this->load->library('email', config);
```

That's an entire day wasted trying every port / server / firewall / security setting imaginable.

I hope this helps someone as dumb as me.